# Limitations and gotchas for email servers

Tags: email, spam, mail-server

I am working for a web-based company that sends large amounts of emails daily (status updates, notifications, etc). Currently we do this via a third part but due to several problems with the service we are considering sending the emails ourselves.

We know the service we are currently using has several limitations in it's systems about how fast it can send emails and how many that can be sent per day, presumably to avoid spam classification. Our largest concern about sending the emails ourselves is to make sure we don't exceed those limitations ourselves.

So on to the question:
When setting up an email service meant to send large amounts of emails, what should we keep in mind? Are there any general limitations save those by our ISP as to how many emails you can send before someone somewhere starts considering you a spammer? What are the risks we would take with doing it ourselves instead of using a third party service (save server errors and the "normal" risks with hosting things)? Should we throttle the sending rate? Etc.

Or a very condensed version of the question:
What to think about when setting up a service to send a lot of emails yourself?

We are also looking at other third party services of course, but we want to be able to weight the options against each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how many emails are you sending per second/minute/hour that the third party service is having trouble with sending these out? Spam is always an issue and a risk when you are an email service provider, but unless you are sending out in the hundreds of thousands per hour, something tells me you would be okay.

When you are setting up your own email service to send large amount of emails, you should probably keep these in mind:

- Make sure your SPF records are accurate and they stay that way
- Incorporate DKIM to complement your SPF records; they aren't widely recognized yet but ISPs like AOL will bounce you away if you don't have DKIM
- Validate the HTML you use in your emails so that you aren't flagged as looking spammy
- Warm up your IP by sending out solid transactional emails over time and not have people report it as spam
- Use external services to check out the status of your IP; the last thing you want is to be blacklisted by large email providers like Gmail, Hotmail, and AOL

There are no real risks with rolling your own mail delivery service, aside from what happens if your IP gets blacklisted from major providers, and what happens to the emails you send when your server is down?

I always advise people to go for third party email providers because it will save you headaches going forward - you can just expect the email to be sent and arrive at the inbox and you won't have to worry about anything.

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com), we have tons of people asking us why go for a third party solution.)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.
We are not sending that many right now, although it will be increasing, but our provider has several larger customers that send a lot more, so their limits probably come from there.

Comment: No problem! The limits are probably what they have established with major providers through testing, but I could be mistaken. Good luck!